# javafx save layout after adding some nodes

Tags: java, javafx-2

simply i made little application .. and i attach button in gridpane so when im click the button generate text field .

```
 @FXML
        private void msgBtn(ActionEvent e) {
            TextField newField = new TextField();
            gp.getChildren().add(newField);

        }
```

the question how i could save the text field generated for later open ?!

any way to save the generated node into xml file or some thing so i can recall it in the next start ?

i read a little about serialized but i didn't get how i approach to my goal through it

can any body help or give me some example ?

Comment: you mean the text in the textfield?

Comment: No I mean the text fields it self.. I gonna call this function in some cases for some users so if I call it I want to keep it for the next run..  How to do this??